# how to simplify a search and filter condition using php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am developing an E-Commerce web application. In this am using filter option to search various product.

The filter options am using are `store, price, discount, color, size`.

For that am used `if else` to make the condition and search it in the database.

My code is,

```
    if($_GET["cid"] != null or $_GET["size"] != null or $_GET["dis"] != null or $_GET["prf"] != null or $_GET["prt"] != null or $_GET["store"] != null or $_GET["cat"] != null or $_GET["sub"] != null or $_GET["brand"] != null) {
        $query = null;
        $query_w = null;
        $query .= 'SELECT * FROM tbl_products a INNER JOIN tbl_product_category c ON c.product_category_id = a.product_category_id LEFT JOIN tbl_product_sec_category sc ON sc.product_sec_category_id = a.product_sec_category_id LEFT JOIN tbl_product_subcategory s ON s.product_subcategory_id = a.product_subcategory_id LEFT JOIN tbl_product_brand b ON b.product_brand_id = a.product_brand_id';

        if($_GET["cat"] != null)
            $query_w .= ' a.product_sec_category_id = "'.$_GET["cat"].'"';
        if($_GET["sub"] != null)
            $query_w .= ' a.product_subcategory_id = "'.$_GET["sub"].'"';
        if($_GET["brand"] != null)
            $query_w .= ' a.product_brand_id = "'.$brand.'"';
        if($_GET["cid"] != null) {
            $query .= ' INNER JOIN tbl_fa_api_color ac ON ac.api_product_id = a.api_product_id INNER JOIN tbl_product_color pc ON pc.product_color_id = ac.product_color_id';
            $query_w .= ' AND ac.product_color_id = "'.$_GET["cid"].'"';
        }
        if($_GET["size"] != null) {
            $query .= ' INNER JOIN tbl_fa_api_size ac ON ac.api_product_id = a.api_product_id';
            $query_w .= ' AND ac.api_size_size = "'.$_GET["size"].'"';
        }
        if($_GET["dis"] != null)
            $query_w .= ' AND (a.api_discount BETWEEN "'.$_GET["dis"].'" AND "99")';
        if($_GET["prf"] != null and $_GET["prt"] != null)
            $query_w .= ' AND (a.api_retail BETWEEN "'.$_GET["prf"].'" AND "'.$_GET["prt"].'")';
        if($_GET["store"] != null) {
            if($_GET["store"] == 'a')
                $query_w .= ' AND a.api_type = "One"';
            else if($_GET["store"] == 'f')
                $query_w .= ' AND a.api_type = "Two"';
            else if($_GET["store"] == 'af' or $_GET["store"] == 'fa')
                $query_w .= ' AND (a.api_type = "One" OR a.api_type = "Two")';
        }

        $query_w .= ' AND a.api_status = 1 ORDER BY a.api_id DESC LIMIT 0,6';

        echo $query. " WHERE".$query_w;
    }
```

`$_GET["cid"]` is `color`, `$_GET["dis"]` is `discount`, `$_GET["prf"]` is `price from`, `$_GET["prt"]` is `price to`, `$_GET["cat"]` is `category`, `$_GET["sub"]` is `subcategory`

In the above code am using concatenation to get the `mysql query`. But my code is not correct. The `mysql query is wrong`.

For example,

`$_GET["cid"] = 1` and `$_GET["dis"] = 12` the current `mysql query` is

`SELECT     *
FROM       tbl_products a
INNER JOIN tbl_product_category c
ON         c.product_category_id = a.product_category_id
LEFT JOIN  tbl_product_sec_category sc
ON         sc.product_sec_category_id = a.product_sec_category_id
LEFT JOIN  tbl_product_subcategory s
ON         s.product_subcategory_id = a.product_subcategory_id
LEFT JOIN  tbl_product_brand b
ON         b.product_brand_id = a.product_brand_id
INNER JOIN tbl_fa_api_color ac
ON         ac.api_product_id = a.api_product_id
INNER JOIN tbl_product_color pc
ON         pc.product_color_id = ac.product_color_id
WHERE
and        ac.product_color_id = "1"
AND        (a.api_discount BETWEEN "12" AND        "99")
AND        a.api_status = 1
ORDER BY   a.api_id DESC limit 0, 6`

where the above code is wrong.

How to make correct `mysql query` using concatenation.

or is there any way to simplify my `if else condition`. Am stuck in here. Thankyou.

Comment: your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries to protect yourself. See http://bobby-tables.com/ for a simple explanation and some PHP examples of how to do it safely. Concatenating strings as you've got there is not safe at all. Your data could be hacked, stolen, corrupted or deleted by a malicious input from a user.

Comment: Anyway, relating to your specific issue, you gave us an example of the "incorrect" query, but didn't explain which part you consider to be wrong, or what you expected the query to look like? "WHERE AND" looks obviously wrong, is that it? Each time you add a clause, you need to check whether you've already added any WHERE clauses or not, and write / don't write an AND at the start of your clause, as appropriate. Quite simply you can check whether $query_w is null or not.

Comment: @ADyson `$query` and `$query_w` should be corrected to display the coreect `mysql query` for all the conditions.

Comment: yes, that's what I just said. But you never defined "correct" in the question. I don't know what your rules are. I've pointed out the syntax error, but I don't know if you consider anything else to be "incorrect" as per your business logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do condition like this way. but, we suggested to you should PDO or mysqli to run this query more securely.

```
if($_GET["cid"] != null or $_GET["size"] != null or $_GET["dis"] != null or $_GET["prf"] != null or $_GET["prt"] != null or $_GET["store"] != null or $_GET["cat"] != null or $_GET["sub"] != null or $_GET["brand"] != null) {
$condition = array();$query_w = '';
$query = 'SELECT * FROM tbl_products a INNER JOIN tbl_product_category c ON c.product_category_id = a.product_category_id LEFT JOIN tbl_product_sec_category sc ON sc.product_sec_category_id = a.product_sec_category_id LEFT JOIN tbl_product_subcategory s ON s.product_subcategory_id = a.product_subcategory_id LEFT JOIN tbl_product_brand b ON b.product_brand_id = a.product_brand_id';

if($_GET["cat"] != null)
    $condition[] = 'a.product_sec_category_id = "'.$_GET["cat"].'"';
if($_GET["sub"] != null)
    $condition[] = 'a.product_subcategory_id = "'.$_GET["sub"].'"';
if($_GET["brand"] != null)
    $condition[] = 'a.product_brand_id = "'.$brand.'"';
if($_GET["cid"] != null) {
    $query .= ' INNER JOIN tbl_fa_api_color ac ON ac.api_product_id = a.api_product_id INNER JOIN sh17n_product_color pc ON pc.product_color_id = ac.product_color_id';
    $condition[] = 'ac.product_color_id = "'.$_GET["cid"].'"';
}
if($_GET["size"] != null) {
    $query .= ' INNER JOIN tbl_fa_api_size ac ON ac.api_product_id = a.api_product_id';
    $condition[] = 'ac.api_size_size = "'.$_GET["size"].'"';
}
if($_GET["dis"] != null)
    $condition[] = '(a.api_discount BETWEEN "'.$_GET["dis"].'" AND "99")';
if($_GET["prf"] != null and $_GET["prt"] != null)
    $condition[] = '(a.api_retail BETWEEN "'.$_GET["prf"].'" AND "'.$_GET["prt"].'")';
if($_GET["store"] != null) {
    if($_GET["store"] == 'a')
        $condition[] = 'a.api_type = "One"';
    else if($_GET["store"] == 'f')
        $condition[] = 'a.api_type = "Two"';
    else if($_GET["store"] == 'af' or $_GET["store"] == 'fa')
        $condition[] = '(a.api_type = "One" OR a.api_type = "Two")';
}

if(!empty($condition)){
    $query_w = implode(' AND ', $condition);
}

if($query_w != '')
    $query_w .= ' AND a.api_status = 1 ORDER BY a.api_id DESC LIMIT 0,6';
else
    $query_w  = 'a.api_status = 1 ORDER BY a.api_id DESC LIMIT 0,6';

echo $query. " WHERE ".$query_w;
}
```

Comment: `WHERE` condition is missing.